# Suppressing messages from the PC Lint Global Wrap up?

Tags: c, pc-lint

I am already setting the 3rd party code files as libraries in my project, but I am still getting messages from those files (libraries) in the Global Wrap-up in the PC Lint output file. Is there a way to suppress the messages from the libraries in the global wrap-up? I am using PC Lint v9.00

Comment: In your pc-lint configuration file you can exclude files/folders, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I already excluded 3rd party files and folders and it is working fine, except for the global wrap-up. I am still getting messages from those files in the global wrap-up section.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by global wrap up, but just add those files as well then to the exclude list?

Comment: At the end of the lint output file, just before the summary, there is a sectional called Global Wrap-up, and I am still getting messages from library files in that specific section. I haven't found a way to suppress those messages yet.          (--- Global Wrap-up)

Answer (score 1):

PC-Lint parses source files tagged as "library" the same way like normal source files but applies a different warning threshold. The option `-w` controls the warning threshold for normal files while `-wlib` controls the warning threshold for libraries. A typical setup would use `-w3` for own code and `-wlib(1)` for library code.

With `-wlib(1)` PC-Lint still reports various major errors regarding library code, which is a good idea because these messages are often related to configuration errors of the PC-Lint project and not the library code itself.
Still it is quite common for 3rd party code to contain code that invokes PC-Lint warnings even at `-wlib(1)`. In this case there are several solutions possible:

- Turn off all warnings in Library code with `-wlib(0)`. This might hide errors related to the project setup though.
- Turn off the remaining library-related messages by using the option `-elib(<x>)` for each error code. In contrast to `-e<x>` using `-elib<x>` disables the error message  for the library code only.

I would like to recommend the second solution unless you have to cope with a really high number of messages.